# Input mask doesn't work when value is deleted

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, masking, maskedinput

I built a function to mask an input when typing and it works fine but when deleting the value in the input the mask behaves strangely.

```js
function App() {
const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState('')

  function maskPhone({ target: { value } }) {
  console.log(value)
  const toMatch = value.replace(/\D/g, '')
    const regex = /(\d{0,2})(\d{0,1})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/
  const [,ddd, prefix, first, second] = toMatch.match(regex)
  setPhone(`(${ddd}) ${prefix} ${first} ${second}`)
 }
  
  return  <div>
      phone: <input type='text' onChange={maskPhone} value={phone} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make almost all the parts of the regex optional with `(?:\s*(\d{n,m}))?` kind of pattern, and then check if the group matched, and build the replacement pattern dynamically. The first part with parentheses also needs a tweak because of those parentheses.

Here is a working solution:

```js
function App() {
const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState('')

function maskPhone({ target: { value } }) {
    console.log(value)
    var reg  = /^(\d{1,2})(?:\s*(\d)(?:\s*(\d{1,4})(?:\s*(\d{1,4}))?)?)?$/
    setPhone(value.replace(/\D/g,'').replace(reg, (_,w,x,y,z) =>  
       ( w.length>0 ? `(${w}` : "") + ( x ? `) ${x}` : "") + ( y ? ` ${y}` : "") + ( z ? ` ${z}` : "") ))
    }
  
  return  <div>
      phone: <input type='text' onChange={maskPhone} value={phone} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: After typing and try edit a initial character you pointer is jumped to end. Why this behaviour happiness and how fixed? Maybe keypress event?

Comment: @Victor No way with this approach, but you may select the digit and press a keyboard to replace that digit.