# Find and replace regex for identification number input mask

Tags: regex, masking, input-mask

I would like help to create an input masking using find and replace regexes for the following use case:

The user types 11 digits of his identification number and the output will be formatted with this pattern:

`\d\d\d.\d\d\d.\d\d\d-\d\d`

**First attempt**

Find: `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})`

Replace: `$1.$2.$3-$4`

This only works after the user types all the 11 digits. However, I want the dots and dashes to appear while the user types.

**Second attempt**

Find: `(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,2})`

Replace: `$1.$2.$3-$4`

As soon as the user types the fourth digit, but the result ends up being like this `\d.\d.\d-\d`

**Third attempt**

Find: `(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})`

Replace: `$1.$2.$3-$4`

As soon as the user types the third digit, but the result ends up being like this `\d\d\d\..-`

**Code**:

A brief description of the code:

```
fun transformation(input: String, findRegex: String, replaceRegex: String): String =
    input.replace(findRegex.toRegex(), replaceRegex)


fun main() {
    
    val input = "01121212"
    
    val findRegex = """(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})"""

    val replaceRegex = """$1.$2.$3-$4"""
    
    val result = transformation(input, findRegex, replaceRegex)
    
    println(result)
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/dPRrIMIVm

Full code can be found here: https://gitlab.com/pertence/masked-textinput

Comment: You forgot to use capturing groups that are referenced with the backreferences.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681441/4770439 works and is the same as my first attempt, but I want I want the dots and dashes to appear while the user is typing.

Comment: Sorry, the regex works on plain text. When user is typing, there is some code that processes the input and applies the regex. What is your code? Also, see [Input mask doesn't work when value is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870518/input-mask-doesnt-work-when-value-is-deleted/60871203#60871203)

Comment: I put the code sample in the question. I know there are other questions about input masking with android compose, but I want to create a class that does not need a custom logic for each mask pattern.

Comment: You cannot make it generic because for each regex pattern you will need a specific replacement. Note `01121212` does not match your pattern. `01121212000` [will match](https://ideone.com/WIXK0d). If you need to replace "partial" matches, you will need a callable in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what would mean by callable? May KCallable be used to implement a callable? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/

Comment: I think you need [this kind of solution](https://ideone.com/CA5AOO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```kotlin
fun transformation(input: String, findRegex: String, replaceRegex: String): String =
    input.replace("""\D+""".toRegex(), "").replace(findRegex.toRegex(), {
        it.groupValues[1].toString() + 
          (if (!it.groupValues[2].isNullOrEmpty()) ".${it.groupValues[2].toString()}"  else "") + 
          (if (!it.groupValues[3].isNullOrEmpty()) ".${it.groupValues[3].toString()}"  else "") + 
          (if (!it.groupValues[4].isNullOrEmpty()) "-${it.groupValues[4].toString()}"  else "")
    })
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = "0112121234" // 011.212.123-4
    // val input = "011" //  011
    // val input = "01121212" // 011.212.12
    // val input = "011212" // 011.212
    // val input = "01121" //  011.21
    // val input = "0112" //  011.2
    val findRegex = """^(\d{3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?$"""
    val replaceRegex = """$1.$2.$3-$4"""
    val result = transformation(input, findRegex, replaceRegex)
    println(result)
}
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/CA5AOO).

**NOTES**:

- `.replace("""\D+""".toRegex(), "")` - removes all non-digits
- `.replace(findRegex.toRegex(), { it.groupValues[1].toString() +  (if (!it.groupValues[2].isNullOrEmpty()) ".${it.groupValues[2].toString()}"  else "") +  (if (!it.groupValues[3].isNullOrEmpty()) ".${it.groupValues[3].toString()}"  else "") +  (if (!it.groupValues[4].isNullOrEmpty()) "-${it.groupValues[4].toString()}"  else "") })` - matches a pattern and replaces the match with different replacements depending on whether a group matched or not.

The regex  is

```kotlin
^(\d{3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2An21n/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `(\d{1,3})?` - an optional Group 2 that matches one, two or three digits
- `(\d{1,3})?` - an optional Group 3 that matches one, two or three digits
- `(\d{1,2})?` - an optional Group 4 that matches one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.